# Connecting to an SQL Server with Mac OS X (Laravel)

Tags: php, macos, laravel

I'm trying to connect to a corporate SQL Server using Laravel on my Mac running Mountain Lion 10.8. I have XAMPP installed with PHP 5.4.19. My list of enabled extensions are:

```
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imap
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mssql
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sybase_ct
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib
```

Unfortunately Laravel has no support for MSSQL which I used in the past with Codeigniter to connect to the server. Which driver am I supposed to specify in Laravel's database configuration file with FreeTDS installed? Do I use ODBC or another method?

```
'sqlsrv' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => 'host',
        'database' => '******',
        'username' => '****',
        'password' => '************',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),
```

I see lots of Mac users using Laravel and I'm really wondering how they manage if they ever have to connect to an SQL Server or any sort of Microsoft SQL product without MSSQL support.

Could anyone please give me some direction or tutorial on how I would possibly connect?

Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry forgot to specify. I installed FreeTDS with MacPorts with the command:

```
sudo port install freetds +mssql +odbc +universal
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use SQL Server connection in Laravel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213907/how-to-use-sql-server-connection-in-laravel)

Comment: @MahmoudZalt No, this issue pertains to Mac, not windows.