# How to troubleshoot PDOException?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, composer-php

I am developing a Laravel application that is talking to a Microsoft SQL server. Everything works, but when I run `composer update` to update packages I receive the following error:

```
[PDOException]
could not find driver

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error

[RuntimeException]
Error Output:

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--] [<packages>]...
```

The strange thing is that the `sqlserv` driver set up in my database.php file works fine; my vagrant box has the correct driver installed and configured and, as far as I can tell, everything regarding the database connection is working as expected.

What steps can I take to try to narrow down the source of this error?

**Update**:

I did mention that my SQL connection is, as far as I know, configured correctly on the server: it works for querying, updating, etc. But just in case I missed something here are the full steps I took to install the SQL driver:

- `sudo apt-get install php5-mssql php5-sybase`
- `sudo php5enmod mssql`
- `sudo nano /etc/freetds/freetds.conf`:

  ```
  [global]
      tds version = 8.0
      client charset = UTF-8
  ```
- `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: couple of posts about the same issue, it may be an issue with your `sqlserv` installation on your server: https://github.com/taviroquai/mapigniter2/issues/16 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213907/how-to-use-sql-server-connection-in-laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this by doing the following:

- Revert PHP 5.6 to PHP 5.5
- Run `composer update` on the actual vagrant vm via `ssh`