# Laravel cli db connect works fine (migrate) but web call throws 'could not find' driver error (odbc)

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, odbc, homestead

> When running php aritisan migrate in the cli it works fine. It creates
>   the tables and the dependencies. But as soon as I try to connect via
>   an ajax call through the web page, I receive the following error:

class:`"PDOException"`
file:`"/home/vagrant/webroot/LaraQ/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php" line:68`

I am using the odbc driver connecting to Intersystems Cache.
This is running on a vagrant box (Homestead) and I have PHP 7.2 running.

Comment: I think you need to check in both `PHP.INI` because cli have a separate ini file and it contains while other not.

Comment: Is this on the vagrant box or my local php?

Comment: in your local php

Comment: I have checked in C:/php there is only one ini file

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mssql
```

Update **/etc/freetds/freetds.conf**

```
[global]  
# TDS protocol version
; tds version = 4.2
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8`
```

Add this line to **php.ini**

```
mssql.charset = "UTF-8"
```

Reference: [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404230/laravel-pdo-exception-cannot-find-driver-even-though-the-driver-is-installed-a)

Comment: Should I then install freetds as as well, as that file doesn't exist?